# linode.com/slicehost.com/vps.net what to chose?

Tags: web-hosting, vps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

I am looking for a new VPS for http://hotelpublisher.com. At the moment it is either linode.com, slicehost.com or vps.net (alternatives are welcome). Since I already use Google cloud to deliver data, my priority is ram/cpu/reliability/price. Can anyone advice which of the VPS providers is the best in their opinion and why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get lower prices for hardware out of [prgmr.com](http://prgmr.com/xen/).  I have used one of their VPS plans for ~6 months now, and had almost zero problems. The trade-off is support. While their system *very* rarely gives me issues, I have had them. And they were my fault and I had to fix them on my own. There's generally somebody on the other end of the line if I send an email for help, but the exchange would normally go something like "I'm getting this error from grub, but I can't track down the problem" "[reply with a link to the prgmr wiki, with an article that answers *most* of my question]".

But they tell you right up front that they aren't here for support. From their homepage:

> - An easy to understand price schedule: $4/month per account, and $1/month for every 64MiB ram. Please note; **this means all plans come with $4/month worth of support.**

Their slogan is also "We don't assume you are stupid."

If you have your configuration down to a science, and you know what you're doing in the shell, you shouldn't have any issues. They've been completely reliable for me since I got my configuration issues ironed out (again, the issues were with my setup, not their VPS).

There are [comparisons](http://journal.uggedal.com/vps-comparison-between-slicehost-and-prgmr) that show prgmr outperforming, in this case, Slicehost by a large margin *at times*. On the flip side, there are [comparisons](http://journal.uggedal.com/vps-performance-comparison) out there that show other VPSs giving higher performance with less hardware for the same price in some situations but have prgmr's performance holding very steady. So evaluate your needs accordingly.

Comment: prgmr.com looks kind of ghetto, but the fact that the owner is publishing a book on Xen (on NoStarch press) is pretty cool.

Comment: The site is just like the service. It works, and it isn't flashy. He's selling you exactly what you're looking for (vps hosting) and nothing else. The epitome of the KISS principle...ha.

Comment: I currently have Dreamhost, which is expiring in January, and after looking at prgmr.com, I might change to them when I get the chance. They look so nice.

Answer (score 1):

I've used rackspace cloud (I believe they bought slicehost) and was very happy it was easy to use, I had no reliability issues, support was fast and helpful and they had a thorough and up to date knowledge base.

Answer (score 1):

There has been discussion on this subject previously, on ServerFault. Here's [a comparison between Slicehost and Linode](https://serverfault.com/questions/56136/slicehost-vs-linode).

I've only used Linode for VPS so far, so can't speak to any other options. However, Linode is easy to get started on, and they have excellent documentation of their offerings and what you can do with them.

Answer (score 1):

I've only used Linode so I can't compare against the others but have to say that I've been over the moon with their service and uptime in the year I've been hosting with them. No problems at all and their replies to my query-tickets were fast and thorough.

Answer (score 1):

I've been a happy Linode user for over four years now. The owners are very accessible, the community has a peculiar energy, they've got a bunch of useful tools, among other things.
And their prices are better than those of prgmr.com.

Noone mentioned Bluemile, they've got the best prices on Xen VPSs I know of. And I didn't see any complains about them so far. Things work perfectly for me on Linode, so I'm not leaving them. But I think anyone looking for options should add Bluemile to consideration.

Answer (score 0):

VPS.net is a reliable VPS hostingprovider.  Their technology allows you to save lots of money, as you literally can scale up or down depending on your workload/needs. You may even opt to you use their CDN, Storage, or Daily VPS upgrades.

Answer (score 0):

I ve been a linode user for 4 years.
I ve recently switched to digitalocean.com, because they provided faster VPS hard disk performance, at half price, and free backups both in USA and EU.
I run my VPS there for a month and they are rock-solid.

Pernally it helps me to learn a lot more about VPS and linux, as it is much less costly to experiment since they are charging per hour.